# PageCount is off by 1 in Telerik Reporting

Tags: c#, telerik-reporting

We have a report using Telerik Reporting that displays the current page out of the total number of pages using the line below.

```
this.textPage.Value = "=\'Page \' + PageNumber + \' of \' + PageCount";
```

However, for this report, [PageCount](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/p-telerik-reporting-processing-renderingresult-pagecount) is returning one number higher than the actual number of pages.

[image: Actually 8 pages]

[image: PageCount returns 9 pages]

My thinking is that maybe there is actually a 9th page that is somehow invisible or not rendered, but I am not seeing anything that would point to that. It seems like if any content or blank space caused wrapping to a 9th page, that this 9th page would also be visible in the viewer.

Any suggestions for how to resolve? Are there any Telerik Reporting APIs that I should specifically look for that could be hiding a page causing this off-by-one issue? I am trying to avoid a hacky `PageCount - 1` solution as I am not sure that would work for all data sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case, we determined that the report viewer could not correctly calculate the total number of pages because the report’s section heights in the designer were too short to display the textboxes within. To fix the bug, we resized the sections in the designer to show all of the textboxes inside them.